# Http status 405 while making $http get request

Tags: angularjs

I am making ajax get request using angular js $http service to yahoo finance rest api however i am getting http status code 405 in response.

below is the complete stack trace.

```
index.html#/tab/stock:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/SUZLON.NS/quote?format=json&view=detail. 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 
header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access. 
The response had HTTP status code 405.
```

Below is my code to make ajax call.

```
var config = {
            headers : {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
                'Accept' : 'application/json;odata=verbose',
                "HOST" : "finance.yahoo.com"
            }
        };

    var promise = null;
    promise = $http.get('http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/SUZLON.NS/quote?format=json&view=detail',config);
    return promise;
```

I am able to make ajax call to google finance api but yahoo finance api is failing.

Do i need to set any header my config object ?
Or is it something different at Yahoo Rest API side which is returning Http 405 ?

Below code for google api call is working fine without setting any header.

```
getNseQuote : function(nseScriptCode) {
    console.log("Inside nseScriptCode : " + nseScriptCode);

    var promise = null;
    promise = $http.get('http://www.google.com/finance/info?q=NSE:' + encodeURIComponent(nseScriptCode));
    return promise;
}
```

Comment: The error message pretty clearly explains what is wrong. Research CORS and/or the same origin policy. TLDR: you can't fix this with your client-side javascript and setting those headers in the config client-side makes no sense.

Comment: It says "Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response." "Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access" I could understand that origin that i localhost:8080 is not allowed. if i run this from finance.yahoo it will work. So does that mean this rest api is designed for internal use only ?

Comment: Any work around to get this done by putting some wrapper around it ?

Comment: You could get the data using your server instead of the client, which is the same suggestion given on the other hundreds of questions involving this error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this extension for chrome link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en). It allows you to do cross-domain request..Also before you integrate the API with your application test the API URL, see if its working using third party tool like [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en) which is best for testing API calls..

Regarding your error 
"**Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 
header is present on the requested resource.**" what it means is that the server is not configured to handle pre-flight request.Pre-flight request is request done by browser in special cases such as when you are requesting data from different domain(when you are doing a request other than GET/POST and using any custom header in your request etc.) for security purpose only (I suppose)..

So, In you case you should use proxy-server which you can make using any open source packages available...In my case I was using [node-http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy).The browser calls the proxy server and the proxy server fetches the data from the actual server and returns it to the browser..it is easy to make with a little bit of tinkering...